# Simple Desktop Shell for HTML Apps

Tags: air, titanium, desktop-application

I am looking for a simple desktop application shell to display an HTML and Javascript application. The web code will be bundled with the app and the app won't need network access. Basically all I need is a window with a webkit view in it I can point to a file on the user's computer.

I thought this would be simple, but I can't find a quick solution to it. What I have looked at so far:

- Adobe Air - Fails due to some crazy security choices that break my web framework.
- Titanium Desktop - Fails due to some strange page loading sequences that result in dom weirdness.
- Chromeless - Looks perfect but discontinued and their download code no longer works.
- PhoneGap - No desktop component.
- XULRunner - Looks very complex for my needs.
- Various others - not cross-platform (I need Windows and Mac), discontinued.

All I want is a simple shell around to display my HTML and run my JS. Please tell me my only solution isn't to use the WebKit view in something like Qt.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not just have a link in their browser that pops up a window containing the local web content?

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/
There are also bindings for using this from other languages like Python.

Answer (score 0):

[AppJS](http://appjs.org) have served me well in creating desktop shells for html5 apps. I think you should give it a try. It's quite easy to tinker with.